# SymmetricDS MalformedURLException

Tags: java, synchronization, symmetricds

I'm configuring two instances of SymmetricDS 3.6.12. The server instance is working in a Glassfish 3 server, using 8181 port as https. The client instance is running as a service (in jetty) with https port in 31417. The two instances are configured and running. The sym_tables at the client was updated with the data from the server, however none of the tables I want synchronize is working. I'm getting this error in server:

```
2014-11-25 23:34:31,493 WARN [ERPServer] [FileSyncService] [erpserver-file_push-1] Could not communicate with node 'PDV:19742872000153:19742872000153' at https://fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:18f%net10:31417/sync/19742872000153 because of unexpected error
java.net.MalformedURLException: Stream handler unavailable due to: For input string: "0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:18f%net10:31417"
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:619)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpTransportManager.getFilePushTransport(HttpTransportManager.java:217)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.FileSyncService.pushFilesToNode(FileSyncService.java:606)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.FileSyncService.execute(FileSyncService.java:593)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.NodeCommunicationService$2.run(NodeCommunicationService.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream handler unavailable due to: For input string: "0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:18f%net10:31417"
at org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.parseURL(URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.java:431)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:614)
... 9 more
```

**MORE INFORMATION**

The server is configured this way:

```
engine.name=ERPServer
group.id=ERP
external.id=19742872000153ERP
registration.url=
sync.url=https://$(ipAddress):8181/symmetric_ds/sync/$(engineName)
```

The client is configured this way:

```
engine.name=19742872000153
group.id=PDV
external.id=19742872000153
registration.url=https://192.168.1.150:8181/symmetric_ds/sync/ERPServer
sync.url=https://$(ipAddress):31417/sync/$(engineName)
```

I've checked the IPv6 that the client is using (fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:18f%net10) and verified that it is a valid IP. Looking at this part of error message:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Stream handler unavailable due to: For input string: "0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:18f%net10:31417"
```

we can see that the url doesn't have the first part of the ip (fe80), instead the port is present at the url (31417). Is this a SymmetricDS bug? Is there something I could do to solve this problem?

Comment: what's the sync.url and registration.url on client? can be found in the engines directory in .properties file

Comment: this doesn't seem like a valid url: https://fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:18f%net10

Comment: the problem is with the ipAddress variable substitution. what's the value that gets written in the file?

Comment: Colon `:` in URL authority separates the port (and password if used) but also is used in IPv6 "literal" format so that needs square brackets. See http://serverfault.com/questions/205793/how-can-one-distinguish-the-host-and-the-port-in-an-ipv6-url . The exception shows the 0:0:0... part because it's trying to parse that whole thing as the (one) port number, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved simply using square brackets in configuration file. As @dave_thompson_085 said in a comment

> Colon : in URL authority separates the port (and password if used) but also is used in IPv6 "literal" format so that needs square brackets.

So I've configured the sync url this way:

```
sync.url=https://[$(ipAddress)]:31417/sync/$(engineName)
```

and did the same in the node table.

Answer (score 0):

The registration url is hardcoded:

```
registration.url=https://192.168.1.150:8181/symmetric_ds/sync/ERPServer
```

and that's the reason why the client successfully registers. The problem is with the `ipAddress` variables substitution. Check why it's replaced with `fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:18f%net10` at the client and have it fixed.

Comment: The IPv6 is correct. I believe SymmetricDS is using the port as part of the IP.

Comment: Take a look at dave_thompson_085's comment